# Prior vs. Marginal Probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

What is the difference between prior and marginal probabilities in layman terms? Do these concepts refer to the same thing, but in the different contexts?

Comment: How so? marginal probability is based on a single variable and prior probability is based on a single variable.

Comment: This is very broad. I would suggest that you add the [tag:self-study] tag, and update your question to explain what you already know. (I *think* I can see where you are coming from, but it is far better to not make us have to guess.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat sloppy definitions:

### Marginal probability

You have two dice. Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the roll of the first die. Let $Y$ be a random variable denoting the roll of the second die.

Let $P(X=x,Y=x)$ be a function giving the probability that $X=x$ and $Y=y$. $P$ is called the *joint probability mass function.* This function defines the joint probability distribution over the two dice rolls.

$P(X=x)$ is called a *marginal probability*. You come to a marginal probability by summing or integrating the joint probability distribution.

$$ P(X=x) = \sum_{y=1}^6 P(X=x, Y=y) $$

Eg. The probability your first die roll is a 2 is the probability you rolled 2 and a 1 plus the probability you rolled a 2 and a 2 plus the probability you rolled a 2 and a 3 etc...

Basically, the *joint probability distribution* is the distribution over all your random variables. And a marginal probability distribution is a distribution that's over fewer than all your variables.

### Bayesian Prior

Let $\theta$ be some parameter that represents your beliefs, some prior beliefs before you see the data. $P(\theta)$ is called a *prior*.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the prior probability can be interpreted as a marginal probability, summed over all possible data that you *could* see. (Given the OP's question "are these the same thing, but in different contexts?")

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I'd still argue that they're getting at fundamentally different concepts, but that's an accurate point that a prior probability is an example of a marginal probability.

The question feels a bit like, "What's the difference between the national debt and a real number?" Well, the national debt may be a number, but they're kinda different concepts...

Answer (score 1):

The *prior*, denoted $P(\omega)$, denotes the probability of some event $\omega$ even before any data has been taken.

A *marginal* distribution is rather different.  You hold a variable value and integrate over the unknown values.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I think we may need more clarification from the OP on what their current understanding is. (For example, in many expositions of Bayes rule, there will be a joint distribution $p(x,y)$ and a prior probability $p(x)$ ... the latter *is* also a marginal probability. So sometimes the marginal probability $p(x)$ is interpreted as a prior probability, and this *is* context dependent.)